# Access an index of multi-dimensional object in depth

Tags: php, json, object, multidimensional-array, dynamic

I have a .json configuration file. Using PHP, I'm trying to get its contents as an object by [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/json-decode) and validate it. The JSON file contains multi-dimensional data. The problem is with accessing a member in depth dynamically.

For instance, consider the following data:

```
{
    "somebody": {
        "name": "Ali",
        "age": 13,
        "life": {
            "stat": "good",
            "happy": true
        }
}
```

How to access the value of the following dynamically?

```
$happy = $data->somebody->life->happy;
```

What I mean from a dynamic access is something like this:

```
$happyIndex = "somebody->life->happy";
$happy = $data->{$happyIndex};
```

Also, I don't want to use [eval()](http://www.php.net/eval).

Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickQ Thank you very much! Should I now delete this question?

Comment: Or just accept the suggested duplicate

Comment: @PatrickQ OK! Again, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a JSON data return

```
 data="{
    "somebody": {
        "name": "Ali",
        "age": 13,
        "life": {
            "stat": "good",
            "happy": true
        }
}"

data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

then you can navigate to different parts of data by navigating

```
    var name= data.somebody[0].name;
    var age= data.somebody[0].age;
```

You will need a $.each function if you have more than one data in "somebody" array.

**PHP Version:**

```
$data='{"somebody":{"name": "Ali","age": "13","life": {"stat": "good","happy": "true"} }}';
$data = json_decode($data,TRUE);

$name= $data['somebody']['name']; 
$age= $data['somebody']['age'];
echo("<pre>");
echo($name);
echo($age);
echo("</pre>");
//OUTPUT RESULT Ali 13
```

Comment: My question is in PHP, not in JavaScript. ;)